# how to delete data from same named but stored in different NSMutablerArray by referencing its name?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uisearchbar

i have created one table view in which i have provided searching & deleting facility. My problem is that when i am not in searching mode the data is going to be deleted properly & shows the table properly after deleting data. but my problem is that i have two NSMutableArrays one is original and second one is searched NSMutableArray so when i delete data from searched Array at that time i want to delete data from original array also.

```
NSString *str = [searchedName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"str:=%@",str);

[searchedName removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[arrName removeObjectIdenticalTo:str];
```

so here my point is that i can't delete original data with use of `removeObjectAtIndex:index.path` because the searched array `count` will be different from original array `count` so from original array it will delete another value witch i have not deleted from searched value.

did you get my point? please mention me if you don't get my point.

how can i implement like this? please guide me.

Comment: you have unique names in original array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first search the index from the original array

```
int index = [arrName indexOfObject:str];
```

Comment: thnks dude it worked perfectly. but i have another problem i have some data are same named like `One,One`.so this data will come same in searched data so how i know that user has deleted the 1 `One` named value not 2 `One`. please tell me if there is another way to delete data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique name in your array then delete that object directly like below...

```
[arrName removeObject:str];
```

Comment: thnks dude it worked perfectly. but i have another problem i have some data are same named like `One,One`.so this data will come same in searched data so how i know that user has deleted the 1 `One` named value not 2 `One`. please tell me if there is another way to delete data. here i get both data are deleted can you have another thing.?

Comment: your original array contain only strings or dictionaries

Comment: thanks your feedback can you provide me some code. ya i have understand it. but is there any other way from that i can delete data from NSMUtableArray not to use of Dictionaries.

Comment: ok i get the point i have done with this i have used an array which one's values are never going to be same. i have used code of @Hanon.